# Dockerfile git clone file permissions

Tags: git, docker

My Dockerfile is setup to use the user "astro".
In the Dockerfile I clone a Git repo:

```
FROM astronomerinc/ap-airflow:0.9.0-1.10.3-onbuild
ENV GITHUB_TOKEN ****
RUN git clone https://token@github.com/owner/my-git-project.git
```

This ends up with root:root permissions, which is not ideal as I have a Python script inside this Dockerfile which is supposed to update the contents of the Git repo:

```
drwxr-xr-x    7 astro    astro          224 Jul 10 14:42 my-python-proj
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 10 18:47 folder_b
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jun 27 09:19 folder_c
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 10 18:47 my-git-project
```

How can I ensure that my Dockerfile default user can write to the Github repo? (A simple chown does not seem to help as subsequent git pulls will add folders with root-only permissions.)

And later I have a Python script that writes to this repo:

```
some_script.py
def makeDirsAndCommit
   //writes some dirs to git repo folder
   //runs git add . 
   //runs git commit
```

Comment: Updated with more relevant contents @michalk

Answer (score 0):

You can create the user in your dockerfile if user `astro` not exist, and switch the user to newly created user so the subsequent command will be run against that user. You can also own any folder during build time.

I am not sure about the Your base docker if the user exist just switch if not then create the one, but this is how you can do this using alpine [nodejs-example from github]

```
FROM alpine:3.8
# install git 
RUN apk --no-cache add git openssh
# create user named appuser


RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup  
RUN mkdir -p /opt/nodejs
# own folder testing
RUN chown -R /opt/nodejs
# switch the user to appuser
USER appuser
RUN whoami

# Test some folder 
RUN mkdir /home/appuser/foldera
RUN mkdir /home/appuser/folderb
RUN  git clone https://github.com/Adiii717/nodejs-helloworld.git /home/appuser/nodejs-app;
```

Build the docker image

```
docker build -t test .
```

Run the container

```
docker run -it --rm --name test test ash -c "tail -f /dev/null"
```

Execute command as a appuser

```
docker exec -it -u appuser test ash
```

Verify folder permission 
[image]

Also, appuser will not allow in root directories

[image]